# ASP.net Core Razor create scheduled task

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, scheduler

I am wanting to create a scheduled couple scheduled tasks on my web site. I am using ASP.Net Core Razor pages. I would like to email reminders the same time each week. Then run a grading task at a specific time each week automatically. I have everything written just no way of scheduling the task. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lots of options.  Look inot Worker services net core.  Write a separate service and schedule it using something like Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: AliK - I am still fairly new to all this. Will this work if I am hosting my web site in a place like Azure or godaddy?

Comment: Yes [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) might help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.